# In Python, how to assign the values of a sparse matrix from the values of another matrix without looping?

Tags: python, matrix

I want to do the following.

I have AA and x. AA's shape and type are

```
(1, 4) <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

the number 4 is just an example. In the real case, I have a very big matrix, like 10000. x's are

```
(4,) <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Now what I want to do is to assign the values of AA with the values of x.

If I do

```
AA=x
```

then AA's type will change to x's, which isn't what I want. I want to keep AA as sparse. If I do looping, it seems not doable when the matrix becoming large. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does (4,) stand for a vector with 4 entries? If so you have a dimensions problem. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks kolonel. This is what I got directly from the type of x. x is actually, for example, set to be x =  np.cos(np.pi*np.arange(n+1)/n), n=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new sparse array with the values of `x`.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
AA = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(x, (1,4))
```